# Magento -> multiple locales for the same language - different websites

Tags: magento-1.9, locale

I have store with multiple websites (different domains). I use one theme, that has different colors/images using:
skin/frontend/default/theme1_blue
skin/frontend/default/theme1_red
skin/frontend/default/theme1_orange
all code is shared on the sam app/code/ dirs.

How to achieve different translations based in skin directories ? translation.csv is based on shared app/code/locale dir, but is it possible to load different translation.csv files based on skin version is used or store view is used ?

Thanks for help
Tomek

Comment: For each store in system configuration under design you can set translation theme.

Answer (score 1):

At System->Config->General->Design under tab themes, you see translation. there you set the same folder as your skin.
In app/design/frontend/package/skindirname/locale/language_CODE/translate.csv

Answer (score 0):

As James is saying, each theme can have its own translation. It should be at:
`app/design/frontend/packagename/themename/locale/locale_CODE/translate.csv`.

Comment: Yes I know it. But I use the same theme for all websites....it has only skin/css skin/images difference
I'd like to avoid loading the same theme files - x times, because all storeviews/websites share the same code. Except skin and it would be great if the translation could be different in some ways - for some word. Probably the best way is DB inline translation for it ?